# Phaser 3 config TypeError - phaser.scale is undefined

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to make my Phaser 3 game mobile friendly and I found the scale manager method in the api, but when I try to add it in my config I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FIT' of undefined`

I am using webpack to import Phaser and I am wondering if that could be part of the issue? I am pretty new to Webpack, but I followed [this really awesome tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUZ8SsLQKUs&list=PLoN_ejT35AEhY4icjiEJ5t2qdunwmQj1R) which uses it.

My config looks like this:

```
import Phaser from 'phaser';
import StartSceen from './StartSceen';
import Instructions from './Instructions';
import PreloadScene from './PreloadScene';
import Scene1 from './Scene1';
import Scene2 from './Scene2';
import GameOverScreen from './GameOverScreen';
import WinScreen from './WinScreen';

const gameConfig = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  domCreateContainer: true,
  parent: 'game-container',
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
    autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
  },
  // StartSceen, PreloadScene,
  scene: [StartSceen, Instructions, PreloadScene, Scene1, Scene2, GameOverScreen, WinScreen],
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 300 },
      debug: false,
    },
  },
};

export default gameConfig;
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why Phaser.Scale is undefined when Phaser.AUTO a few lines above works fine?

Comment: No clue what Webpack is, but are you using the newest version of Phaser? Check in the JavaScript console for something like `Phaser v3.19.0`

Comment: I am using Phaser v3.15.1. I'll try updating and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, but I updated Phaser to the version 3.55.0, and it worked fine CDN: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.0/dist/phaser.js`